# Quick Action display repetitively in the layout

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, quickaction

I am facing the problem standard quick action on TASK like Change date, edit comment,Change Priority, Change Status ( quick action) are showing two timeswhen we click on show more action in the task page layout salesforce lightning.

I found the solution that we can override the global publisher layout in the task page layout, and remove the duplicate values(Action type is same, only api name is different- which are genrated by system only i did not done any customization).

But my concern is how this duplicate values is created.

Can any one suggest why it happen.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you're on the Tasks page when using the Global Task action, you're essentially calling an Action to create or edit a Task which I'd expect to open a new pop-up to create or edit a Task for that page using the Tasks page dialogue. On completion it should returns you to that page again. However, you're already on that page, thus the reason for duplication.

Since you're already on the Task Ojbect, you need to be using an Object-specific Action for Task.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B55BAA5RXyMzWkU0THJSRnVmejQ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Thanks For your response [Link] https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B55BAA5RXyMzWkU0THJSRnVmejQ/view?usp=sharing   Please see the shared link, it may help you to understand my problem, here it shows Change date is two time, Edit Comment 2 times. API name is same but when i explore in deep i have seen for 1 "change date" API Name - Defer and for another "Change Date" is Defer_0 like wise.

Comment: In your screen capture, it appears as though both are defined as Global Actions. You'll want to define one of them as an Object Specific Action and move it to the correct menu on the page layout. You may want to rename the Object Action at the same time, which could also be part of the source of your issues.

Comment: Thanks for your response, all this are standard action i am not allow to edit this.
Please share steps how can i achieve this.

Comment: Depending on what you did and what you want to do, I recommend you read the following tutorials to learn the proper methods: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.fundamentals.meta/fundamentals/adg_chatter_actions_global_create.htm and https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.fundamentals.meta/fundamentals/adg_chatter_actions_object_try.htm. One or the other should help you solve your issue.